# Замена фрагмента внутри фрагмента с помощи Android Navigation

Tags: android, android-navigation-view

В приложении есть фрагмент внутри которого HorizontalScrollView с несколькими кнопками и FragmentContainerView. При нажатии на кнопки фрагмент в контейнере должен изменятся. Но я не понимаю как это сделать через Android Navigation. Он дает возможность заменять фрагмент целиком, но не фрагмент внутри контейнера.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вам надо видимо получить внутренний navController и переход делать в нем.